# Creating buffer causing nodejs app to crashed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

```
router.post('/image', multipartMiddleware , function(req, res) {


   var file_name = req.body.name;
   var data = req.body.data;

   var stream = fs.createReadStream(data); //app crash here


   return s3fsImpl.writeFile(file_name , stream).then(function () { 
        fs.unlink(data, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        });
        res.status(200).end();
    });

});
```

Was trying to upload base64 image but the app will crash; if I skip that line I will get broken image file in S3. I'm using a package called s3fs here https://github.com/RiptideElements/s3fs

Answer (score 0):

`fs.createReadStream` takes first argument as file path.

eg: /user/x/file.txt

Looks like you should do something like

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(file_name);
```

Comment: I'm uploading a base64 image, why would I need to create a buffer? am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

`fs.createReadStream` can throw multiple errors, if path is not passed, if it not exists, etc.

BTW `fs.createReadStream` is for reading files from you filesystem. I guess you were trying to crate a stream from a buffer.

According to s3fs docs, there is no need to do this. You can just pass you data to `writeFile` try

```
s3fsImpl.writeFile(req.body.name, req.body.data);
```

Comment: if I skip that, the uploaded base64 image is broken.

Comment: If body.data is in base64 and you need a buffer you can do this new Buffer(req.body.data, 'base64');